# Variable loses its value in a function and it doesnt add

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>


int sumadig(int a);

int sumadig(int a){
    
    return a==0? 0 : a+sumadig(a-1);    
}


int sumadif(int a, int b);

int sumadif(int a, int b){
    
    if(a==b) return a;
    
    int ares = a;
    int asum;
    int bsum;
    asum = 0;
    bsum=0;
    
    while(a!=b && a!=0){
        asum+=a;
        a>0? a-- : a++;
    }
    
    while(b!=ares && b!=0){
        bsum+=b;
        b>0? b-- : b++;
        printf("%d / %d \n", b,bsum); // Line used for debugging.
    }
    
    asum+=bsum; 
    
    return asum;    
}


int main(void){
    
    int x,y;
    
    for(int i=1;i<=2;i++){
    printf("Ingrese un numero %d:\n", i);
    scanf("%d", i==1? &x : &y);
    }
    
    sumadif(x,y);
    
    
    printf("Resultado: %d", sumadif(x,y));
    printf("\n Suma numero 1: %d Suma num2: %d", sumadig(x), sumadig(y));
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, the function is not doing `(asum+=bsum)` thus returning only `asum`. Besides I noticed that the last while loop iterates one more time than necessary. Why is it?

When the variable `b` reaches 0 it kind of goes back to 4 and `bsum` goes back to 0.

Comment: Could it be that you are confused by the fact that you call `sumadif` twice with the same arguments, and so all debug output is duplicated? [I don't see](https://godbolt.org/z/sxc5eM) any evidence of anything untoward going on. What input do you use when running this program, what outcome do you expect, and what do you observe instead?

Comment: I need to see the sum of all the numbers from 0 and each of the two parameters but it must work for both negative and positive numbers

Comment: I mean, one of the parameters could be negative

Comment: So, what inputs do you pass in (whether positive or negative), what result do you observe, and what result do you expect instead? Note also that `sumadig` exhibits undefined behavior if ever passed a negative value.

Comment: Why `b!=ares` in `while(b!=ares && b!=0)`?

Comment: I passed 505 and 4 and it returned 127765 which is only the 505 part.

Comment: Show the **exact text** of the output you desire for input “505 4”. Preferably, also show the output you expect for the inputs “5 3”, “5 -3”, “-5 3”, and “-5 -3”.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider input be 5,6
Here is how your loop works.

```
while(a!=b && a!=0){
    asum+=a;
    a>0? a-- : a++;
}
```

As a<b first condition is always satisfied so out loop will be stopped by a=0. Which means.5+4+3+2+1=15. Which is the value of a sum at the end of your loop.

> Now control moves towards another loop.

```
while(b!=ares && b!=0){
    bsum+=b;
    b>0? b-- : b++;
    printf("%d / %d \n", b,bsum);
}
```

> We assigned Ares = a and value of ares=5

So the loop will run as

> Iteration 1

bsum+=b --->0+6
b-- i.e.b--->5

> Iteration 2

b!=Ares fails. As b= 5 and Ares =5

```
asum+=bsum; 
return asum;
```

> asum+bsum ---> 15+6---> 21

Looking at your question it seems as if you wanted sum upto X and sum upto y. For that you can change loops as:

```
while(a!=0){
    asum+=a;
    a>0? a-- : a++;
}
while( b!=0){
    bsum+=b;
    b>0? b-- : b++;
    printf("%d / %d \n", b,bsum); 
}
```

Change the recursive function to.

```
int sumadig(int a){
    if(a>=0){
        return a==0? 0 : a+sumadig(a-1);
    }else{
        return a+sumadig(a+1);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In `main` you don't need to call `sumadif` before doing it in the `printf.

I can't get the logic of this his statement in `sumadif`

```
if(a==b) return a;
```

What were you trying to do?

Always in `sumadif`, the while loops have redundant stuff and could be written in a easier way using for loops (and forgetting about `ares`)

```
for(int i = a; i > 0; i--) {

    asum += i;
}

for(b = a; b > 0; b--) {

    bsum += b;
}
```

Also you could initialize asum and bsum in the declaration

```
int asum = 0;
int bsum = 0;
```

And please stop using Turbo C.

Edit: I read the text of the problem "Given two integers a and b, which can be positive or negative, find the sum of all the integers between including them too and return it. If the two numbers are equal return a or b." and I made a program. You always need to keep things as simple as possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int a, b, res = 0;

    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);

    if( a > b ) {
        
        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }
    
    for(int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        
        res += i;
    }
    
    printf("%d", res);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm tryingto do this https://www.codewars.com/kata/55f2b110f61eb01779000053

Comment: @LeonardoContreras I made an edit to answer that

Comment: Re “This loop in the main `for(int i=1;i<=2;i++)` Runs only for i = 1”: Put that in a program and try it.

Comment: What about the part when I wrote "Edit: actually I missed the = sorry."

Comment: Delete the wrong part in the answer; do not just add some note about it.